# Error while launching android studio after upgrade from 4 to 4.1 (MacOS 10.15)

Tags: android, android-studio

*got this error after upgrade **Android Studio** from 4 to 4.1 I am using macOS 10.15*

[image]

I tried to delete the google folder by navigating to the hidden system folder by

**Command+Shift+G.**

**/usr/discreet/**

but can't find any folder named google

Answer (score 1):

I have same situation in windows, and i fixed by deleting the C:\Users\USERNAME.AndroidStudio whatever version folder.

After that close and open android studio it will show a dialog in that i clicked "do not import"

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue in Linux i did this,
android studio not opening properly after updated. Just press CTR+H in File manager (show hidden files). now you can see the .local file. now go to remove the google file from there. (Path -> local/share/google).